# How to display FPS counter in BFBC2?

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2

I've read that you can display FPS counter in battlefield 2 bad company with a command similar to BF2 (renderer.drawFps 1)

Pressing tilde seems to open a console, however I can't type anything in.
I'm using an AZERY keyboard.

Did someone find a way to display FPS ?

Answer (score 5):

Download [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) for free and it will allow you to display FPS and take screenshots etc. works for everything to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: there is no console in Bad Company 2. There is only a messages screen, which is accessed by pressing tilde as you've seen.

So you're stuck with Fraps to show your FPS in-game.

Answer (score 0):

"Press the ~ key to toggle the console, and type:
renderer.drawfps 1 "

Last entry in the page, ignore all the priors that are similar to Red's.

[source for above](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/384744.page)

Comment: -1 he said he can't type anything